# Why in OOP languages most codes always declare methods everywhere insteads of containing "flat instructions"?

Tags: java, oop

I'm having hard time to understand the OOP logic. For instance I noticed in OOP languages such as java or python the programs always define some methods in the linearly executed program. I have a little experience in C and I don't understand the point of doing that.

**For instance why write :**

```
public class test {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\sele"));
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

....

}
```

**Instead of :**

```
public class testjv {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\sele"));
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

....

}
```

Given that I don't intend to use testjv class elsewhere but in this executed file ?

Comment: That's how the language is defined.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun : do you mean my second example won't even compile ?

Comment: And if you had 5000 lines of code? Wouldn't it be nicer to break it into chunks ("methods"), instead of having it all lumped together?

Comment: It won't, try it. Instructions should be written inside a method.

Comment: Because you may want to call setUp method more times from other parts of the program. Should you write the same code again? It has nothing to do with OOP btw

Comment: well in C I declare a function outside the main or the function I'm working in, but with OOP languages you just declare the method **WHILE** still executing it, it's a bit odd to me.

Comment: @Wicelo  declare the method WHILE still executing it? What????

Comment: well in C when you declare a function you don't execute it until you call it. Here you declare the method and execute what it contains. If `public void setUp() throws Exception {..}` was just declaring the method `setUp` then I would have to call it later in the code with `setUp();`  but I don't, it's content is getting executed.

Comment: Your previous comment is false. You still have to call functions just like you described.

Comment: well in the example I give in my post I don't call setUp(); anywhere

Answer (score 3):

The underlying assumption is actually incorrect. The code is not executed in a linear fashion. For example, in a JUnit test, the methods annotated with "@Before" get invoked repeatedly (once before each "@Test" method), and a similar concept applies to the older version of JUnit (i.e. the method named "setUp" gets invoked before methods whose names start with "test"). With different test runners, the order of tests being invoked can be changed (for example, there is a proprietary implementation of a test runner that executes tests in parallel to confirm that the code under test is actually thread-safe).

But, going more generally than this specific case, there are several reasons to do this:

1. Reusability - breaking down blocks of code into smaller, named units allows these subunits or subroutines to be invoked in multiple different contexts, without needing to call the entire program.
2. Debugability - naming subregions of code allow for stack traces to identify the specific region of code at which a particular error occurred. This is a much easier way of understanding the code than simply looking at line numbers (and having to find the line number in some previous revision).
3. Isolation - each logical subsection of the code probably does not need access to all of the different variables or data in use in the program. Declaring functions and their inputs limits the scope of access such that the implementation only has access to the variables that are relevant to it.

There are probably more benefits/reasons than this, but these are the ones that come to mind first.

Answer (score 0):

```
Given that I don't intend to use testjv class elsewhere but in this executed file ?
```

To plainly answer this yes if you donot intend to put the operations on data variables inside a method then you can either put them in constructor or you can put it inside a initialization block (both end in the same thing)
eg for initialization block :-

```
{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Now the reason why OOP languages donot allow operations on data variables outside a method is assume a scenario where in when you construct an object of this class you donot want your above lines of code to run automatically as in above case. How would you prevent this? So if these lines of code are in method then you have the control over the operations performed within the class on the data variables. You can even **override** these operations and define your own operations. You can even restrict other classes from calling your data modification operations by declaring your method private which is **encapsulation**.